# Moore-Penrose pseudo inverse algorithm implementation in Matlab

Tags: matrices, numerical-methods, matlab, numerical-linear-algebra

I am searching for a Matlab implementation of the [Moore-Penrose algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_pseudoinverse) (convertable to C++) computing pseudo-inverse matrix.

I tried several algorithms, ["Fast Computation of Moore-Penrose Inverse Matrices" from Pierre Courrieu](http://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/0804/0804.4809.pdf) appeared good at the first look. However, the problem is that for large elements it produces badly scaled matrices and some internal operations fail.

It concerns the following steps:

```
L=L(:,1:r);
M=inv(L'*L);
```

I am trying to find a more robust solution which is easily implementable :-). Thanks for your help.

Comment: In what way does it fail, do you get an error message and if so which?

Comment: Enter `>>edit pinv` you could see the key step here is singular value decomposition.

Comment: Have you considered routines like LAPACK? http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lug/node32.html

Answer (score 1):

Use the inbuilt function `pinv(...)`.

Comment: Of course, there is. But it does not solve the problem. I would like to know, how it works and implement it in another SW.

Comment: @justik Do you explicitly need the pseudoinverse, or do you just need the action of the pseudoinverse on a vector?

Comment: Isn't there some library like LAPACK that already has what you want implemented for C++?

Comment: @justik, as long as your computing environment allows you to compute the singular value decomposition of a matrix, then it is not too hard to construct the Moore-Penrose inverse.

Answer (score 1):

MATLAB uses the SVD for the [`pinv()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pinv.html) function (Just do `edit pinv.m` in MATLAB).
The SVD, I believe, is basically a warpper around Intel MKL's SVD Function.

Comment: Thank you. I did not know the code is available by `edit pinv.m`.

Answer (score 0):

It's not Matlab unfortunately but the open source numpy implements pinv in python, which may be of some use, code can be found here:
https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/linalg/linalg.py#L1508